# Acessing Items on a Masterpage from a Child page

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have a `<ASP:Label ID="lblDashboardLink" runat="server" />` located on a MasterPage named **MasterBase**.

From a page using this MasterPage, how can I access this `label` or any other items I need?

```
'VB.NET
'(From the child .aspx page)
Master.FindControl("lblDashboardLink"). <-- but don't see an option to change URL
```

I've been googling and I keep finding this same method, but it's focusing more on User Controls it looks like... Can anyone guide me in the right direction here?? I'm so used to MVC!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Master.FindControl("lblDashboardLink") always returns a `Control` (see [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/486wc64h.aspx)). So all you have to do is **cast it to Label**. Then you may access any properties of a Label. Anyway there is no URL property in a label...

```
CType(Master.FindControl("lblDashboardLink"), Label).Text = "your value"
```

Comment: Yeah I realized I need to make it a Hyperlink, but just cast it as `, HyperLink).NavigateUrl = "http://..."` and it worked! Thanks so much, forgot about CType!

Comment: glad i could help. one more tip - have a look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xxwa0ff0.aspx - adding a master page type may be very helpful!

Comment: Nevermind i'm an idiot, reading that article I see it's real easy to save it as a `Dim` and reuse it faster :) Thanks again!

Comment: If you found my answer was helpful and solved your question you may consider marking it as "correct/best answer" thx in advance

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
CType(Master.FindControl("lblDashboardLink"), Label).Text = "some url"
```